# Rendering using both GPU and CPU is not possible

Tags: rendering, gpu, performance

For some reason I'm unable to render on CPU+GPU. I've checked on 2 different computers and it's not available. One setup is Threadripper + GTX 1070, and the other one Intel i9 + GTX 1080.

Is it a matter of supported processors or I have to activate it somehow?
I'm using Blender 2.79b

Answer (score 1):

In fact it IS possible. You need to download a branch like this:

http://graphicall.org/1240

...and many others on this site. Open Settings and in the System pane You will find settings as on the image below. Hope it helps, buddy.

Sincerely, Jan

*REM: Sometimes using GPU+CPU could be SLOWER then using GPU only!*
[image]

Comment: Or simply download one of the daily builds from the blender website.

Comment: Yep, that will do too.

Answer (score -1):

Using CPU and GPU at the same time is not supported in Cycles yet. To get this functionality you would need to switch to another renderer like the [AMD ProRender](https://pro.radeon.com/en/software/prorender/).

Comment: It is available with Cycles on all daily builds of 2.79 and 2.8.